# Textbooks on the Schwarzschild-de-Sitter Metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, resource-recommendations, cosmological-constant, de-sitter-spacetime

Does anybody know a textbook on the geometry of the Schwarzschild-de-Sitter metric and its maximal extension? It's not in Hawking & Ellis.

Comment: [Does this help](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9910029v1)? [Possibly also this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02722226)

Comment: Thanks, John! I notice that one has to dig into papers to learn this metric. and papers are either hard to read or not holistic.